# Preventing iOS mobile browsers from forcing open apps when clicking links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, jquery-mobile

I have a website which contains links to external websites, for example amazon product links. The links work just fine, but when I test my website on mobile (iOS in this case), I noticed that clicking the links in the mobile browsers would force open the Amazon app rather than just opening a new tab.

The links in my html are as follows:

```js
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank"></a>
```

I want to have these links open in the browser only, not in their respective apps. Is there any way in to prevent this behavior using html / javascript? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @abpatil - I added in an example of the links in my html. Thanks!

Comment: Would you be so kind as to mark the answer as accepted? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

The reason is: you should not be able to impose *your* choice on the user. Maybe the user prefers the app? That's why iOS 9 introduced the app switcher on the top left hand corner if you switch apps.

Also, let's look from the other side of things if you are the app developer: If you go so far as to build an app and allow universal links (or generally deep links), you obviously would like the user to use that feature and rather open the site in the app. But again, you cannot force the user into opening that link in the app. That's a good thing, because it all depends on what the user wants to do and how he wants to do it.

Having the user choose is the best way to handle this from a UX point of view.